# Empty logger in iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm learning to use the `logging` module  in Python (3.6.0) and started with an example from the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations). However, when the code is run from within a loop the log messages are repeated multiple times. Why is that? Is there any way to empty the loggers in this case? I tried to play around with `logger.propagate` but had no success.

My code in the script `testlog.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging

def main():
    t = (1,2,1,2,1)

    logit('Log is fine here', '_logfile', logname='INFO', level='info')

    for i,x in enumerate(t):
        if x == 1:
            logit('Warn at iter {}'.format(i), '_logfile', logname='INFO', level='info')


def logit(message, logfile, logname='LOG', level='info'):
    '''https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations'''

    logformat = '%(asctime)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s\t%(message)s'
    dateformat = '[ %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S ]'
    # set up logging to file
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=logformat,
                        datefmt=dateformat,
                        filename=logfile,
                        filemode='a')

    # define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # set a format which is simpler for console use
    formatter = logging.Formatter(logformat, datefmt=dateformat)
    # tell the handler to use this format
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    # add the handler to the root logger
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
    # Now, we can log to the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
    console.propagate = False

    if level.lower() == 'debug':
        logger.debug(message)
    elif level.lower() == 'info':
        logger.info(message)
    elif level.lower().startswith('warn'):
        logger.warning(message)
    else:
        logger.error(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
> ./testlog.py 
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Log is fine here
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 0
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 0
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 4
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 4
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 4
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 4
```

**EDIT1**: the idea is to log to both the console and to a log file.
In the log file the messages are not repeated.

```
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Log is fine here
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 0
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  01:59:09 ]       INFO     INFO    Warn at iter 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it to work in the following way (with most of the code adapted from [here](https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/logging-to-console-and-file-in-python/)). 
First a function was needed to create the logger and add the different handlers to it. Each handler can have it's own set level:

```
def set_logger(logfile, logname='LOG'):

    logformat = '%(asctime)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s\t%(message)s'
    dateformat = '[ %Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S ]'

    # Setup Logging Object
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Set log object to console
    chandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    chandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(logformat, datefmt=dateformat)
    chandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(chandler)

    # Set log object to file
    fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile,
                                    mode='a')
    fhandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(logformat, datefmt=dateformat)
    fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fhandler)

    return logger
```

Then logger can be retrieved in main():

```
def main():

    logger=set_logger('_logfile')

    t = (1,2,1,2,1)

    # logit3('Log is fine here', '_logfile', logname='INFO', level='info')
    logger.debug('Log is fine here')

    for i,x in enumerate(t):
        if x == 1:
            # logit3('Warn at iter {}'.format(i), '_logfile', logname='INFO', level='info')
            logger.debug('Warn at iter {}'.format(i))
```

the output in console is:

```
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Log is fine here
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 0
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 4
```

the output in log file is:

```
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Log is fine here
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 0
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 2
[ 2017-03-04  11:21:02 ]       DEBUG    LOG Warn at iter 4
```

Not sure if this is the most appropriate approach, but for now is working as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

It's specifically because of the following line in `logit`:
`logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)`

Every time you call `logit`, you are adding another `StreamHandler` to the root logger. You should do all the configuration of the loggers once.

Comment: I see, but what would then be the best way to add a new handler (console in this case) to the root logger. Apparently it is not possible to set filename and handlers together in the logging.basicConfig()

Comment: Generally, you setup the loggers once. You can create another method called `setup_logging` which takes a file as a parameter and returns the logger. Then your `logit` method takes in the message, the logger and the level. So, your `main` method would have a `logger = setup_logging('my_log.log')` and your calls to `logit` would look something like `logit(logger, 'my message', 'info')` (At that point, though, you probably wouldn't need your `logit` method and can just call `logger.info('my message')` directly)

Comment: Can you give specific examples?